# i have to transfer cust data to book. any possible method ? let me know please

Tags: django, orm, model

```
from.models import Book,Cust

Cust.objects.get(acc, no1)
Book.objects.create(ac="acc",no="no1")

INSERT INTO Book (ac, no) SELECT ac, no FROM Cust.
```

*i have to convert to django orm query how to do ?*

Comment: Maybe you can provide the info from where to where you want to transfer the data, probably from one database to another. Its not possible to address your  question tthe way it is posted.  Please read the site question requierements.

Comment: Erick. all the cust data have to dump book Data table

Comment: I want like this. INSERT  INTO Book (ac, no) SELECT ac, no FROM Cust.

Comment: i think you can understand now very clear

Comment: Erick. You got wrong. i meant that transfer one data table to another data table. not meson DATABASE ok

Answer (score 0):

Let me insist on asking you to provide sensible information in your questions.
So you can get started have a look at two basic methods:

Access the data in the database where (I'm assuming) both tables are installed and run the INSERT query you are mentioning;

Or  add a method in your django's models.py to either of your models such as:

```
................
class Book(models.Model): 
.........................  
    def updateBook(self):
        set = Cust.objects.all().values('ac','no')
        for e in set:
            self.create(ac = e.cust, no = e,no)
```